# Restkit Serializing a Boolean from NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, serialization, restkit, nsnumber

One of managed objects has one attribute 'isMember' represented by NSNumber type. When serialize to Json post body by RestKit, it always give 0/1 instead of YES/NO or true/false. When mapping from json result to objects, RestKit is able to successfully turn YES/NO to NSNumber. What is the way to force serialize the boolean attribute to YES/NO or true/false?

```
Serialize: 0 -> 0, 1 -> 1

Deserialize : YES/true -> 1, NO/false -> 0
```

Comment: 0 and 1 is equivalent to NO and YES and BOOL is an integer-compatible type. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I double check the Json doc and found out the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NSNumber representation, 0 is equivalent to NO, and 1 is equivalent to YES; furthermore BOOL is an integer-compatible type, usually an unsigned char. There's no contradiction here.

Comment: The problem is that a BOOL is serialized to 0 or 1 in json. However, servers to which the json is send expect true or false.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the delegate method to manually change the value:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didSerializeSourceObject:(id)sourceObject toSerialization:(inout id<RKRequestSerializable> *)serialization
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = ((NSDictionary*)*serialization).mutableCopy;
    NSNumber *value = [params objectForKey:@"myBoolean"];
    [params setObject:value.boolValue ? @"true" : @"false" forKey:@"myBoolean"];
    *serialization = params;
}
```

**Update**

I found out that this only works when your sending the body as normal text/html parameters. When setting the *serializationMIMEType* of the *RKObjectManager* to *RKMIMETypeJSON* then the serialization object will be the json as an NSData. In that case you could still manipulate the serialization object but you would have to parse the json, change it and then serialize it again.